# Matplotlib over multiple files with internal filtering

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to assemble a line graph for itemW which is represented once in an iterated list of many files. Each file has many items (say, itemA-itemW) which are not necessarily in order but are each followed by one number that would be the y value(the x value comes from the file name). Any ideas on how to iterate into matplotLib over this number of files with dynamic positioning? Thanks!

Comment: Ok, so your limitation is the lines joining the points, right? Because if you plot only the points that wouldn't be a problem. I don't think there's an easy way to do what you want. The points have to be supplied at once and in the correct sequence, AFAIK, so the points are joined by lines correctly. Since you're already iterting through these several files, I would suggest processing them into arrays/dataframes and plot these later.

Comment: Yes, the limitation is making this into one continuous series. So then I suppose it's an iteration with a "for" loop which appends each file's relevant section to the data frame.